# any way to improve current time series plot output in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have managed to manipulate my plotting data to render the corresponding time series plot. But I am not quite satisfied with the current output because it is not easy to understand the newly generated plot.

**my current data and my output**:

here is my data looks like:

[image]

**update**

here is my sketch code that shaped above plot data:

```
df=df.groupby(['date'])['qty1'].sum().reset_index()
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month
plot_data=df.groupby(['year', 'month'])['qty1'].sum().unstack().fillna(0)

plot_data.plot(kind='line')
```

and based on this data, I am getting this plot:

[image]

but this is not what I expected for.

**desired plot**:

Here is the plot that I actually want it:

[image]

I didn't get this plot. How can I get this? any idea?

Comment: possible for you to put a df.to_dict() output ? It will be good to try for a solution with the data you are using.

Comment: Yes ...I am working on it ...pls expect an answer with the desired plot in next 30 -40 mins .. :)

Comment: answered - pls accept the answer if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @instinct246 yes I am going to accept it for sure. I am thinking about how to generalize your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(dic) #dic is the dictionary you provided in the github link
df.columns = [str(i) for i in range(1,13)]
df = df.T
df.columns = ['2014','2015','2016','2017','2018']
df['Avg'] = df.mean(axis =1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,7))
plt.plot(df.index,df['2016'], marker='s',color = 'green', linewidth = 1, label="2016")
plt.plot(df.index,df['2017'],"bo-", linewidth = 1.5, label="2017")
plt.plot(df.index,df['2018'],  marker='s', ms =10, color = 'red', linewidth = 3, label="2018")
plt.plot(df.index,df['Avg'],  "--", color = 'grey', linewidth = 8, label="5-Yr-Avg")

plt.xlabel('\n Months\n', fontsize = 25, color = 'lightslategrey')

plt.legend(frameon = False, loc = "lower center", ncol=len(df.columns), fontsize = 14)
plt.grid(axis='y')
ax.set_xticklabels([calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in range(1,13)])


plt.tick_params( left = False, labelsize= 13)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)



plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am thinking about to generalize your solution, I mean vectorize your code and make it efficient.